# JS: how to target specific parent using parentElement

Tags: javascript

Trying to grab the computed height of the `order-body` of the FIRST container when attaching an event listener to the `price` in the 2nd container.  I am stuck right now.

```
<div class=“order-body”>
   <div class=“product-details”>
       <div class=“price”>
          $9.99
        </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class=“order-body”>
   <div class=“product-details”>
       <div class=“price” id = “foo”>
            $5.99
        </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class=“order-body”>
   <div class=“product-details”>
      <div class=“price”>
         $10.99 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>




let price = document.getElementById(‘foo’);

function increaseContainerHeight() {

    event.target.parentElement.parentElement.style.height = “200px”
    event.target.parentElement.parentElement.style.transition = “all 1s”



    // the height’s value is “” before I set it so transitioning it goes from “” to “200px” , which won’t transition properly since it goes from no value to “200px”

}


price.addEventListener(‘click’, increaseContainerHeight)
```

The problem with the above is that it will do the job of increasing the outer container to 200px but it won’t transition because it doesn’t have a starting height to transition from so I want to get the computed height and then transition it to 200px:

```
function increaseContainerHeight() {

// setting the height to the computed height , which is “67px”

   event.target.parentElement.parentElement.style.height = window.getComputedStyle(event.target.parentElement.parentElement).height

// THEN increment the height so it can transition 

   event.target.parentElement.parentElement.style.height = “200px”
  event.target.parentElement.parentElement.style.transition = “all 1s”
}
```

But now after all of this, I realize I am setting and changing the  `order-body` container on the SECOND container which contains the element I have my eventListener attached to, but I want to target the first.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have pre-defined `height` in your CSS, you already have a start point.

To get the first `div` you might traverse to the closest `.order-body`.

You may use `.closest('.order-body')` or `.parentElement.parentElement` (if you have to support IE), then get its `previousElementSibling`.

See the snippet below:

```js
let price = document.getElementById('foo');

price.addEventListener('click', increaseContainerHeight)

function increaseContainerHeight(event) {
  var first = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling
  first.style.height = '200px'

}
```

```css
.order-body {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #396;
  transition: 1s;
  height: 67px;
}
```

```html
<div class="order-body">
  <div class="product-details">
    <div class="price">
      $9.99
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="order-body">
  <div class="product-details">
    <div class="price" id="foo">
      $5.99
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="order-body">
  <div class="product-details">
    <div class="price">
      $10.99
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what’s going on with the height there.  Say the order-body already has a defined height of 67px.  I want to use that height to transition to the new height of 200px.

Comment: @Rayy, if you've defined `height: 67px`, sure you can transition it to the new value.

Comment: The height is there from the CSS but when I go to get the element’s `style.height`, it’s always “” because the CSS value is stored in the computed height

Comment: @Rayy, you might get the `height` as `element.offsetHeight`, but you don't need to set it again.

Comment: @Rayy, also in your example you're setting first `height = 200px` then `transition`, so `transition` has start point of `200px`.

Comment: So my question is , do I need a starting point or does it know the starting point?  Because when I query the height using `element.style.height’, it’s always an empty string “” — that’s why I was unsure if I need to set the element.style.height to computedHeight of the element THEN set it to the height I want it transition to.

Comment: @Rayy, if `height` defined in CSS, you already have a start point. `element.style` returns styles applied _inline_ with `style` attribute.

Comment: Perfect, that clears it up.  Thanks for your help @KoshVery !

Answer (score 0):

This will get the initial starting height that you said you need to transition from:

HTML:

```
<div class="order-body" style="height: 200px;">
    <div class="product-details">
        <div class=“price”>
            $9.99
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="order-body" style="height: 100px;">
    <div class="product-details">
        <div class=“price” id = “foo”>
            $5.99
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="order-body" style="height: 50px;">
    <div class="product-details">
        <div class=“price”>
            $10.99 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script defer src="test.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
// order-body array
const h = document.querySelectorAll(".order-body");

for (let i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight
    // includes padding
    console.log(h[i].clientHeight);
    // >> 200
    // >> 100
    // >> 50

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight
    // includes padding, scrollBar, borders
    // console.log(h[i].offsetHeight);
}
```